# R dygraph title on two lines

Tags: r, dygraphs

In R, How would I get the title of a dygraph to go over two lines.

Below is what I tried, but it didn't seem to work...any help would be much appreciated...

```
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
dygraph(xts(rnorm(100),Sys.time()+seq(100)),main='random\ngraph')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the HTML `<br>`:

```
dygraph(xts(rnorm(100),Sys.time()+seq(100)),main='random <br> graph')
```